# Сколько памяти занимает обьект?

Tags: java, netbeans

Как узнать сколько занимает памяти `ArrayList`, или простые `object`?

Java 1.7-1.8, NetBeans

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Например, можно использовать package [java.lang.instrument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html).

Скомпилируйте этот класс в JAR:

```
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;

public class ObjectSizeFetcher {
    private static Instrumentation instrumentation;

    public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation inst) {
        instrumentation = inst;
    }

    public static long getObjectSize(Object o) {
        return instrumentation.getObjectSize(o);
    }
}
```

Добавьте следующую строчку в `MANIFEST.MF`:

```
Premain-Class: ObjectSizeFetcher
```

Теперь можно использовать `getObjectSize`:

```
public class C {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.println(ObjectSizeFetcher.getObjectSize(new C()));
    }
}
```

Запускается так:

```
java -javaagent:ObjectSizeFetcherAgent.jar C
```

---

<sub>Перевод [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52682/276994) с en.SO</sub>

Comment: Хм, а проще никак да?

Comment: Надёжно — судя по всему, нет. Кроме того, не забывайте, что внутри объекта могут быть ссылки на другие объекты — может быть, вы захотите прибавить из размер к размеру исходного объекта.

Comment: Да, а я думал он сможет обнаружить и внутренние и плюсавать их, ну ладно

Comment: @ДенисКотляров: Не, не сможет. Потому что если у объекта есть ссылка на другой объект, то непонятно, этот другой объект — на самом деле часть вашего объекта, или просто так сбоку стоит. Например, если у вас есть листовой узел в дереве, который имеет ссылку на корневой узел — считать корневой узел частью листового узла или как?

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле, очень интересный вопрос. Покопавшись в библиотеке [ehcache-sizeOf](https://github.com/ehcache/sizeof) нашел в ней несколько способов определения размера объекта:

1. С помощью **Reflection**. Подход довольно тривиальный, зная у объекта класс, мы можем определить какие у него и его "родителей" есть поля и вычислить *приблизительный* размер. Так же к этому значению стоит добавить размер заголовка. Более подробно можно посмотреть в исходниках класса [RelflectionSizeOf](https://github.com/ehcache/sizeof/blob/2b6a596a444e1152a833dabe127b3ffa5c61d37f/src/main/java/org/ehcache/sizeof/impl/ReflectionSizeOf.java)
2. Следующий подход представляет из себя использование хорошо знакомого класса `java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation`. Самостоятельно создать объект данного класса нельзя. Поэтому для получения экземпляра класса приложение запускается с нужным **Java агентом** который, в свою очередь, сохраняет объект в `static` поле. После того как агент закончил свою работу,  можно уже будет вызвать метод `Instrumentation::getObjectSize` который в свою очередь вызовет `native` метод `jvm`. [`AgentSizeOf`](https://github.com/ehcache/sizeof/blob/2b6a596a444e1152a833dabe127b3ffa5c61d37f/src/main/java/org/ehcache/sizeof/impl/AgentSizeOf.java)
3. Так же есть возможность воспользоваться **непубличным api** стандартной библиотеки, а именно классом `sun.misc.Unsafe`. Алгоритм не сложный. Опять же зная, какие есть поля у класс мы можем определить смещение. Делается это с помощью метода `Unsafe::objectFieldOffset`, а уже на основе смещения можно вычислить и размер объекта. Подробности реализации в классе [`UnsafeSizeOf`](https://github.com/ehcache/sizeof/blob/2b6a596a444e1152a833dabe127b3ffa5c61d37f/src/main/java/org/ehcache/sizeof/impl/UnsafeSizeOf.java)